# Get the value of a tables's cell depending on the x and y coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

as i am new to jQuery i would like to ask the following, i have a table like this:

```
<table id="lettersGrid" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td>..</td>
  <td>..</td>
  <td>..</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>..</td>
  <td>..</td>
  <td>..</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

i want to use jQuery to get the value of a specific cell depending on the x and y position of it, so i have

```
$("td").mouseover(function(){
 x=this.parentNode.rowIndex;    //get the x coordinate of the cell 
 y=this.cellIndex;      //get the y coordinate of the cell

 //??whats next??
});
```

any help?

Comment: You don't need them if all you want is to get the value - just use the "this" reference you already have from the mouseover event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the content of the cell that you are "mouseing-over"

```
 $('td').mouseover(function(){
     var content = $(this).html();
     //do whatever you like with the content....
 });
```

Edited: Use the [index](http://api.jquery.com/index) function to get the col/row values

```
 $('td').mouseover(function(){
     col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
     row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
 });
```

To Select similar rows:

```
 $('table tr').eq(row).find('td');
```

To Select similar cols:

```
 $('table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(col);
 }
```

To find the value of a specific row + col

```
 $('table tr').eq(row).find('td').eq(col).html();
```

Comment: no i would like to take the value with the coordinates because later on i will get the value of all cells which have the same y lets say..

Comment: yes but your code does not give the value based on the coordinates, i have found that this for example $('#lettersGrid').find("tr").eq(5).children().first() gives you the fifth tr but what about a complete function that includes specific td too..?

Comment: maybe its the last one tha would help me but it does not work here:

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     
   var a=$("#lettersGrid tr").index(1).find("td").index(2).html();
  alert(a);
  });
});

<body>
<table id="lettersGrid" border="1">
<tr>
 <td>a</td>
 <td>b</td>
 <td>c</td>
 <td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>e</td>
 <td>f</td>
 <td>g</td>
 <td>h</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>i</td>
 <td>j</td>
 <td>k</td>
 <td>l</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>m</td>
 <td>n</td>
 <td>o</td>
 <td>p</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button>Press to get the value</button>
</body>
</html>

Comment: i have found something really interesting that solved my problem, it was that simple:

`$('#lettersGrid tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').html();` to get the element at col=1 row=1 **starting from 0**

or

`$('#lettersGrid tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').html();` to get the element at col=1 row=1 **starting from 1**

Comment: Sorry - you're correct - didn't get chance to test it earlier, but should have used eq instead of index when dealing with numbers. However, your solution is cleaner!

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/ZgDgZ/)

```
$("button").click(function() {
    var row = $('input.enterRow').val()- 1;    // -1 CAUSE .eq() IS zero BASED
    var cell = $('input.enterCell').val()- 1;
    var value = $('#lettersGrid tr:eq(' + row + ') >td:eq(' + cell + ')').html();

    $('.result').html( value );               // PRINT VALUE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had told it at a comment before but just to be clear enough for someone with the same problem,i have found something really interesting that solved my problem, it was that simple:

`$('#lettersGrid tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)').html();`to get the element at col=1 row=1 **starting from 0**

or

`$('#lettersGrid tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1)').html();` to get the element at col=1 row=1 **starting from 1**